# I am trying to write a jpa query for subqueries

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am trying to write a JPQL query for subqueries.  The query is as follows.

```
select 
    fos_name, count(ALLOCATION_BUCKET) as bucket_count
from
    (select 
        *
    from
        kic.master_mis
    where
        ALLOCATION_DATE IN (select 
                max(ALLOCATION_DATE)
            from
                kic.master_mis
            group by BILLED_ID))
where
    date(ALLOCATION_DATE) Between 'starting day month -14' AND 'till the date the month completes 30 or 31 days' group by fos_name`
```

I am using MySQL native query but now there is a variable period now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using a typed query and creating a list for the inner query.

```
    TypedQuery<Integer> query1;
            query1=getEntityManager().createQuery("select max(m.misId) from MasterMis m group by m.billedId",Integer.class);
            List<Integer> distinctRows1=query1.getResultList();
TypedQuery<Object[]> query3;
                query3=getEntityManager().createQuery("select m.fosName,count(m.allocationBucket),sum(m.totalOutstanding), count(m.lastDispositionCodeFOS),count(m.totalCollection), sum(m.totalCollection) from MasterMis m where m.misId IN :distinctRows1 "+"and m.allocationBucket like '%B0%' and m.allocationDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate group by m.fosName",Object[].class);
                List<Object[]> s1=query3.setParameter("distinctRows1", distinctRows1).setParameter("startDate", startDate, TemporalType.DATE).setParameter("endDate", endDate, TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
```